# How can I make my login session faster?

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, linq, authentication

I have a working login page that I coded using both the Entity Framework with JS + jQuery (for validation). The thing is that the code takes a very long time load (45 secs max), I think it's because of the script, my question is, is there a way of making my code look more simpler just so I could improve performance?

Here's a snapshot :[image: Snapshot]

Basically, the script includes code to prompt the user if either the fields are empty or one of the fields are empty (username or password). And I know the problem is not with my pc because other projects run much faster except for this one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace BloodBankSystem
{
    public partial class LogIn_Page : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string Username;
      //  public int role { get; set; }
       // public BloodBankDataContext context = new BloodBankDataContext();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  LblError.Visible = false;
        }

        public static string CreatePasswordHash(string plain_password)
        {
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plain_password);
            data = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256().ComputeHash(data);

            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        }

    protected void ShowMessage(string Message, MessageType Type)
    {
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ShowMessage('" + Message + "','" + Type + "');", true);
      ShowMessage("Invalid username and password combination.", MessageType.Error);
    }

    public enum MessageType { Success, Error, Warning };


    public static Tuple<int,bool> IsValidLogIn(string username, string password)
    {
      bool valid = false;
      int role ;
      using (BloodBankSystemDataContext context = new BloodBankSystemDataContext())
      {
        Donor user = (from _user in context.Donors
                      where _user.DonorKey == username &&
                     _user.Password == password
                      select _user).FirstOrDefault();

        Staff admin = (from _admin in context.Staffs
                       where _admin.StaffKey == username &&
                       _admin.Password == password
                       select _admin).FirstOrDefault();


        password = CreatePasswordHash(password);

        if (user != null)
        {
          role = 2;
          valid = true;        
        }
        else if (admin != null)
        {
          role = 1;         
          valid = true;         
        }
        else
        {
          role = 0;
          valid = false;          
        }


        return  new Tuple<int, bool>(role, valid);
        // tuple;
      }
      }


        public void LogIN()
        {
            string strPassword = Page.Request.Form["TxtPassword"].ToString();
            string strUsername = Page.Request.Form["TxtUsername"].ToString();
            bool valid = IsValidLogIn(strUsername, strPassword).Item2;
            int role = IsValidLogIn(strUsername, strPassword).Item1;

      // string strLogIn = Page.Request.Form["btnLogIn"].ToString();

      if (!(strUsername.ToString().Equals("")) || !(strPassword.ToString().Equals("")))
      {
        if (valid)
        {
          if (role == 1)
          {
            Response.Redirect("StaffHomepage_Page.aspx");
          }

          if (role == 2)
          {
            Response.Redirect("Home_Page.aspx");

          }
        }
        else if (IsValidLogIn(strUsername, strPassword).Item2 == false && IsValidLogIn(strUsername, strPassword).Item1 == 0)
        {
          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + "Invalid username and password combination!" + "');", true);
         // ShowMessage("Invalid username and password combination.", MessageType.Error);
          LblError.Visible = true;

        }
      }
      else
      {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "DoValidate();", true);
        ShowMessage("Invalid username and password combination.", MessageType.Error);
      }
        }
        public void LogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "DoValidate();", true);
          // LblError.Visible = true;
            LogIN();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In my experience , when the returned `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` is small, then  doing a toList and then firstOrDefault is much faster. Try doing something like `YourLinqQuery().ToList().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Jaya, I will try it out thanks.

Comment: Call `IsValidLogIn` only once, something like `var login = IsValidLogIn(strUsername, strPassword);` and then on the next two lines you can do `bool valid = login.Item2;` and `int role = login.Item1;` and the same goes later on in that else if. Also: why are you calculating the passwordhash *after* you queried the database? By the looks of it the passwords are in clear text in your Donors and Staffs tables.

Comment: But none of these explains a 45 second duration. I'm also quite a bit worried about the Redirect to either user or admin. You may want to look into the ASP.NET Roles provider instead of building your own login logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues. #1 your password hash generation is *after* you do your lookup? This would mean that passwords were stored plain-text.

But to the performance issue: Breakpoints and database profilers can tell you a lot about performance. Set a breakpoint on:
 `using (BloodBankSystemDataContext context = new BloodBankSystemDataContext())`

How long does it take to spin up a DbContext? Large, complex contexts can take a while to spin up. In cases like that, adopting more of a bounded context approach (smaller contexts to serve specific areas, such as authentication) can improve performance.

Next, you are constructing the context and calling the database twice per login:

```
bool valid = IsValidLogIn(strUsername, strPassword).Item2;
int role = IsValidLogIn(strUsername, strPassword).Item1;
```

With the tuple result this should have been:

```
var tuple = IsValidLogIn(strUserName, strPassword);
bool valid = tuple.Item2;
int role = tuple.Item1;
```

Though I don't recommend using Tuples, just create a private container to return the relevant details you want, plus an enumeration for the role rather than an arbitrary Integer value. This leaves it more readable. Update the login validation method to return an instance of this result container rather than a Tuple. For instance:

```
private enum UserRoles
{
   None = 0,
   User,
   Admin
}

private struct LoginResult
{
   bool IsValid = false;
   UserRole Role = UserRoles.None;
}
```

then

```
public void LogIN()
{
  string password = Page.Request.Form["TxtPassword"].ToString();
  string userName = Page.Request.Form["TxtUsername"].ToString();
  LoginResult result = ValidateLogin(userName, password); //I renamed IsValidLogin which implies a Boolean result.

  if (!result.IsValid)
  {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "DoValidate();", true);
    ShowMessage("Invalid username and password combination.", MessageType.Error);
    return;
  }

  switch(result.Role)
  {
    case UserRoles.User:
       Response.Redirect("Home_Page.aspx");
       break;
    case UserRoles.Admin:
       Response.Redirect("StaffHomepage_Page.aspx");
       break;
    default:
       // Handle something unexpected?
  }
}
```

Try to avoid a lot of conditional code (ifs, elses, all nested around) this makes code complex, hard to follow, and leaves lots of room for buggy situations to crop up. Unexpected combinations of conditions lead to unplanned execution paths.

Next, use `.Any()` in the Entity Linq lookup:

```
bool isDonor = context.Donors
                 .Any(d => d.DonorKey == username 
                        && d.Password == password);

bool isAdmin = context.Staffs
                 .Any(s => s.StaffKey == username 
                        && s.Password == password);
```

SQL will execute that as a far more efficient query since you don't need to consume any of the details about the entities. If you do need details, use a `.Select(x => new { ... })` to return the values needed from the object model. This is more efficient than loading entities and potentially dealing with things like lazy loading.

Finally, use a profiler against your database to look at what queries are being run at any given time and extract the SQL being run so that you can execute that manually and assess it's execution plan. This can reveal a lot of problems, anything from lazy loading calls, something causing a lot of repeated calls, and indexing improvements. For SQL Server I can recommend ExpressProfiler (https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) It's simple and effective.